# How to pre-process RGB segmentation mask for multi-class semantic segmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I am working on a multiclass semantic segmentation dataset, the dataset has RGB ground truth segmentation masks for the original images. The dataset has 24 classes. The following table displays the classes and their respective RGB values:

| name | r | g | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| unlabeled | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| paved-area | 128 | 64 | 128 |
| dirt | 130 | 76 | 0 |
| grass | 0 | 102 | 0 |
| gravel | 112 | 103 | 87 |
| water | 28 | 42 | 168 |
| rocks | 48 | 41 | 30 |
| pool | 0 | 50 | 89 |
| vegetation | 107 | 142 | 35 |
| roof | 70 | 70 | 70 |
| wall | 102 | 102 | 156 |
| window | 254 | 228 | 12 |
| door | 254 | 148 | 12 |
| fence | 190 | 153 | 153 |
| fence-pole | 153 | 153 | 153 |
| person | 255 | 22 | 96 |
| dog | 102 | 51 | 0 |
| car | 9 | 143 | 150 |
| bicycle | 119 | 11 | 32 |
| tree | 51 | 51 | 0 |
| bald-tree | 190 | 250 | 190 |
| ar-marker | 112 | 150 | 146 |
| obstacle | 2 | 135 | 115 |
| conflicting | 255 | 0 | 0 |

Sample RGB Ground Truth Segmentation Mask Image:

[image: Sample RGB Ground Truth Segmentation Mask Image]

There are 400 images in the dataset, each having a shape of (4000 px **X** 6000 px). The directory structure of the dataset is shown below:

```
dataset_folder
├── original_images
│   ├── 000.png
│   ├── 001.png
│   ├── ...
|   ├── 399.png
|   └── 400.png
└── masks
    ├── 000.png
    ├── 001.png
    ├── ...
    ├── 399.png
    └── 400.png
```

I want to create semantic segmentation masks from the RGB masks, by assigning integer values to the pixels in the range 0-23 (where each integer represents a class) and save them to the working directory. Can someone please suggest an efficient code for this task?

Comment: Hi I tried using the code I found here: [https://www.bulentsiyah.com/preprocessing-rgb-image-masks-to-segmentation-masks] maybe it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
My solution is probably not the most efficient, but as there is no other answer, i share it anyway :

First get an array from the image, opening it with openCV for example..

For the example, let's make an "image" of 4*3 px with three channels:

```py
img=np.array([[
    [128, 64,128],
    [  0,  0,  0],
    [  0,  0,  0],
    [  0,  0,  0]],
   [[128, 64,128],
    [  0,102,  0],
    [  0,  0,  0],
    [  0,  0,  0]],
   [[130, 76,  0],
    [130, 76,  0],
    [130, 76,  0],
    [130, 76,  0]]])
```

[image: chanelimg]

Make a dictionary of the RGB values associated with the mask's wanted value (i wrote it down by hand for the example, but you can do it using pandas if you have a table as shown above), then make a list of the values encountered in the image, and finally create the mask with the corresponding categorical value.

```py
unlabeled = str([0, 0, 0])
paved_area = str([128,  64, 128])
dirt = str([130,  76,   0])
grass = str([  0, 102,   0])

labels = {unlabeled:0, paved_area:1, dirt:2, grass:3}

print(labels)
>>> {'[0, 0, 0]': 0, '[128, 64, 128]': 1, '[130, 76, 0]': 2, '[0, 102, 0]': 3}

width = img.shape[1]
height = img.shape[0]

values = [str(list(img[i,j])) for i in range(height) for j in range(width)]
print(values)
>>> ['[128, 64, 128]', '[0, 0, 0]', ..., '[130, 76, 0]']
print(len(values))
>>> 12      # width*height 

mask=list([0]*width*height)
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    mask[i]=labels[value]

mask = np.asarray(mask).reshape(height,width)

print(mask)
>>> array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 3, 0, 0],
           [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

[image: mask]